# angular component not updating

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I am trying to update angularjs component but component not updating.
setting isLoggedin in the controller as false and after submitting the user info in registerUser chaging the isLoggedin as true but it is not updating the scope in the navbar.

angular component is

```
.component('navBar',{
controller: "registerController",
bindings:{
    nav:'<'
},
controllerAs:'vm',
templateUrl:'./components/navbar.html'
})
```

template is

```
<header  >
<div class="menu">
    <div id="websitelogo" class="logo">
      <h1><a href="/">escapo.in</a></h1>
    </div>
    <form id="search-form" >
      <input  name='search' ng-model="search" placeholder='Search ' type="text"/>
      <input id='button-submit' type='submit' ng-click="searchNav();" value='Search'/>
    </form>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="clickEvent"  onclick="openNav();" class="collapse">&#9776;</a>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul id="links" >
      <li  ng-if="isLoggedin">
          <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="dropbtn" onclick="openDropDown()">{{vm.username}}
              <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </li>
      <li  ng-if="vm.isLoggedin"><a href="/login" class="fa fa-sign-in"> Login {{vm.isLoggedin}}</a> </li>
      <li  ng-show="vm.isLoggedin"><a href="/register" class="fa fa-user"> Sign up</a> </li>
      <li><a href="/">{{vm.isLoggedin}}</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

controller is

```
app.controller('registerController',["$q","$scope","webApi","Handler","redirect","$state","$location",
function($q,$scope,webApi,Handler,redirect,$state,$location){
  var defered = $q.defer();

var vm = this;
  vm.isLoggedin = false;

//login function 
$scope.login = function() {
    var data = {
        email: $scope.email,
        password: $scope.password
    };
        webApi.login(data)
}

//register User
$scope.RegisterUser = function() {
    var data ={
        email : $scope.email,
        password : $scope.password,
        username: $scope.username,
        dob : $scope.day +" "+ $scope.mon + " " +$scope.year,
        gender : $scope.gen
    }
    webApi.register(data)
    .then(function(response){
      console.log(response);
      vm.isLoggedin == true;
      console.log($scope.isLoggedin);
    },function(err){
      defered.reject(err);
    });
}
}]);
```

here i declared isLogged as false and after registerUser i want to update the isLoggedin as true.

Comment: You are mixing up `controllerAs` sytntax with `$scope` syntax in both controller and template

Comment: That is a very sketchy use of `$q.defer()`.

Comment: If your using component then controllerAs syntax is preferred instead of using $scope